# Что означает следующая ошибка? PHP, SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

При запросе возникает следующая ошибка:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: mode must be an integer
```

Впервые столкнулся с ней

Код выглядит следующим образом:

```
<?

    require_once('includes/db.php');
    require_once('includes/requests.php');

    $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

    try {

        $getArticle = $_GET['single'];

        $STHArticles = $DBH->query('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE article_categorie = ', $getArticle);
        $STHArticles->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $rowArticles = $STHArticles->fetch();

        echo $rowArticles['title'];

    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {  
        echo "Ошибка...";  
        file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);  
    }

?>
```

В таблице мы имеем такие столбцы:

```
id
title
article_categorie
content
```

Адресная строка: `/?single=1`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16187536/5441700

Comment: пожалуйста, прочитайте про метод `query` внимательно.

Comment: Может проще использовать такую `row='{$value}'` модель добавления переменных в SQL запрос?

Comment: Дополню совет товарища And: "пожалуйста, прочитайте про метод query внимательно **и больше никогда его не используйте**". Для чего вообще устанавливать коннект через PDO, а потом использовать этот метод? В самом деле, использовали бы дальше mysql_*

Answer (score 1):

У вас ошибка в строке:

```
$STHArticles = $DBH->query('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE article_categorie = ', $getArticle);
```

Согласно документации для метода query, второй параметр должен быть int. Подробнее тут: http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.query.php

Можно попробовать переделать код следующим образом:

```
<?

require_once('includes/db.php');
require_once('includes/requests.php');

$DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

try {

    $getArticle = $_GET['single'];
    // заменим этот метод на prepare
    //$STHArticles = $DBH->query('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE article_categorie = ', $getArticle);
    $STHArticles = $DBH->prepare('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE article_categorie = ?');
    $STHArticles->execute(array($getArticle));
    $STHArticles->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $rowArticles = $STHArticles->fetch();

    echo $rowArticles['title'];

}
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo "Ошибка...";  
    file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);  
}

?>
```

Comment: Непонятно за что минусят, при том что ответ верный.

Answer (score 0):

Это значит, что `$getArticle` содержит тип `string`. Если вы точно уверены, что там будет тип `int`, том можете выполнить явное приведение типов:

```
$getArticle = (int) $_GET['single'];
```

Или используйте метод`PDOStatement::bindParam` - он позволяет указать передаваемый тип данных:

```
$statement->bindParam('param1', $getArticle, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```